# Create date wise log of executed queries on MySql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sometime I make changes on local database but forgot to write/copy query to made changes.

I want to create log file which contain all changes I made in Database with:

```
 log file with date 
eg. mySql_log_03_10_2019.log
```

File must created on @ 12:00 AM

Many developers like me may face this problem.

Comment: When you do in local copy the script and paste in a text file.

Comment: @James Yes I do it but if in case  I forget to copy when give more attention to development/coding or other things?

Comment: If you have enterprise edition you can use audit log to log those by day wise  or MySQL Workbench offers a history in which queries were executed as logged by day wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After searching, I found following ways:*

- Using table
- Using log file

**First run**

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Then

**For table:**

```
SET global log_output = 'table';
```

For retrieve for particular date:

```
select * from mysql.general_log WHERE DATE(event_time) = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

**For log file:**

```
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = "path to log file";
```

like. `"D:/xampp/mysql/data/logs/mysql_general.log"`

Both methods have pros/cons.(table/file size ...)

Hope it help someone.